# Wordpress Blog URL

Tags: wordpress, blogs

For some reason my blog posts are creating their own URL's.

Blog is on `www.website.com/blog/` but when I make a new post, the new post URL is `www.website.com/new-post-url/`.

What I want is for the blog posts URL to be `www.website.com/blog/new-post-url/` as their URL.

I use All in One SEO as my SEO plugin (if that matters).

Comment: Probably that SEO plugin matters. Anyway check the Permalinks (http://<your-wordpress-install>/wp-admin/options-permalink.php)

Answer (score 3):

You should check your blog setting.
login as administrator and go **Settings >> General Settings**
check here **Site Address (URL)**. This should be **http://www.website.com/blog**

Hope this is helpful.
all the best ;)

Answer (score 2):

@user1667462

Have you checked your .htaccess file?

Because you when you're having /blog kind of redirect to your WordPress Blog then you must have to add below code in your .htaccess file

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
>
> RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings -> PermaLinks** from **Dashboard** and select **Custom Structure**

give `/blog/%postname%/`

Check your blog by going to any post/page.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Wordpress admin panel and check to ensure that permalinks are set to the appropriate settings. Also check to make sure that your theme is not overriding the settings you might have chosen. Some themes for example can explicitly request you set a blog page for the blog posting which can interfere with what you assume to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your go to admin page and click setting page, change the url types.